# Django Rest Framework GeoDjango Serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework, geodjango

Is there a way to create a serializer using the User model that shows the locations stored under that user?

I can create regular location serializers, however, I want to be able to create a url like the following:
localhost.com/api/users/username-goes-here/location

On this page I want it to display all the locations of that specific user.

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = serializers.PointField(source='location.location')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'location')
```

> The error I get is:  AttributeError: module
>   'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'PointField'

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rest framework doesn't come with default serializer point fields to support geometry fields.

Please check the below library for that.

```
https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis
```

or you can create your custom serializerfields

```
from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeometryField


class GeometryPointFieldSerializerFields(GeometryField):

    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        try:
            value = value.split(",")
        except:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Enter the co-ordinates in (latitude,longitude). Ex-12,13")
            )
        try:
            latitude = float(value[0])
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Enter the co-ordinates in (latitude,longitude). Ex-12,13")
            )
        try:
            longitude = float(value[1])
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Enter the co-ordinates in (latitude,longitude). Ex-12,13")
            )
        value = {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
        }
        value = json.dumps(value)
        try:
            return GEOSGeometry(value)
        except (ValueError, GEOSException, OGRException, TypeError):
            raise ValidationError(
                _('Invalid format: string or unicode input unrecognized as GeoJSON, WKT EWKT or HEXEWKB.'))

    def to_representation(self, value):
        """ """
        value = super(
            GeometryPointFieldSerializerFields, self).to_representation(value)
        # change to compatible with google map
        data = {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                value['coordinates'][1], value['coordinates'][0]
            ]
        }
        return data
```

in serializer you can use the above fields

```
class UserTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = GeometryPointFieldSerializerFields(source='location.location')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'location')
```